# How to handle dimension changes on tileset? (Tiled)

Tags: tiled

I am using Tiled map editor.

My question is:
What should I do if I would like to change the dimensions of the graphic file for the tileset? The IDs will shift if I will not adapt the graphic accordingly.

My idea is to write a simple script that can swap/shift the IDs in the map.
Is there a better way? Or is there a script already that I can use?

Answer (score -1):

Well, if I'm not wrong, the IDs won't shift unless you add/remove tiles from the tileset. So simply changing the dimensions (higher resolution for example) won't change the order of the tiles and therefore the IDs will stay the same. Have you already tried what happens?

If the IDs change you could implement some kind of mapping table. So that you use one simple tileset for drawing the map in Tiled, which is then, maybe depending on platform or resolution, mapped to the real tileset during map load. What do you think?

Comment: Of course the tiles shift. Consider for example a tileset graphic 320x320 with tile size 32x32. So there is ID 11 first in second row. Now resize the graphic to 640x320. Suddenly the first tile in the second has ID 21. - I "solved" the problem now by implementing a "swap tile" functionality in Tiled.